# SparkContext.parallelize a lazy sequence?

Tags: apache-spark

Can I pass a lazy sequence (e.g. an interator) into `SparkContext.parallelize` call? I'd like to stream a large number of items without having to put them all on the heap.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, the data needs to be sliced and sent to the workers. During slicing it will be loaded into memory on the driver.
It can only be avoided if you are parallelizing a Range, but I don't think that's your case.

Parallelize method accepts a Seq and not an Iterator...

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to stream in a large number of records from a database (yes I'm aware of the difference HDFS input makes). It looks like I need to go via a flattened text file in order to get the data in. It seems strange that there isn't another option. After all, it's technically possible to lazily read an iterator and create pages on the fly.

Comment: In that case you can probably use JdbcRDD to directly load the data from the database

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can use this from Java (or Clojure)? I've tried with the example but without much luck.

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but from what I gather, you should be able to use it from Java 8